# Why is the `Idx` type parameter of the `Index` trait allowed to be unsized?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer

In Rust 1.14, the [`Index` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.14.0/std/ops/trait.Index.html) is defined as follows:

```
pub trait Index<Idx> where Idx: ?Sized {
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

The implicit `Sized` bound of the `Output` type is relaxed with `?Sized` here. Which makes sense, because the `index()` method returns a reference to `Output`. Thus, unsized types can be used, which is useful; example:

```
impl<T> Index<Range<usize>> for Vec<T> {
    type Output = [T];  // unsized!
    fn index(&self, index: Range<usize>) -> &[T] { … } // no problem: &[T] is sized!
}
```

The `Idx` type parameter's implicit bound is also relaxed and can be unsized. But `Idx` is used by value as method argument and using unsized types as arguments is not possible AFAIK. **Why is `Idx` allowed to be unsized?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is just an accident of history. That looser bound [was introduced in 2014](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/9f1217da9132551ee5708c16aba821fe3c671d09). At that time, the trait looked a bit different:

```
// Syntax predates Rust 1.0!
pub trait Index<Sized? Index, Sized? Result> for Sized? {
    /// The method for the indexing (`Foo[Bar]`) operation
    fn index<'a>(&'a self, index: &Index) -> &'a Result;
}
```

Note that at this point in time, the `Index` type was passed *by reference*. Later on the [renamed `Idx` type changed to pass by value](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/bc1dde468c1613743c919cb9f33923cc9916c5b4):

```
fn index<'a>(&'a self, index: Idx) -> &'a Self::Output;
```

However, note that *both* forms coexisted in the different compiler bootstrap stages. That's probably why the optional `Sized` bound couldn't be immediately removed. It's *my guess* that it basically was forgotten due to more important changes, and now we are where we are.

<s>It's an interesting thought experiment to decide if restricting the bound (by removing `?Sized`) would break anything... maybe someone should submit a PR... ^_^</s>

Thought experiment over! [Lukas submitted a PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/38895)! There's been discussion that it might break downstream code that creates subtraits of `Index` like:

```
use std::ops::Index;
trait SubIndex<I: ?Sized>: Index<I> { }
```

There's also talk that someday, we might want to pass dynamically-sized types (DSTs) by value, although I don't understand how.

Comment: Great answer as usual!

Comment: *There's also talk that someday, we might want to pass dynamically-sized types (DSTs) by value, although I don't understand how.* => There's a difference between language and implementation. Just because the language considers it a move (pass by value) does not imply that at ABI level the value is not passed by pointer. And thus it is perfectly sensible to have the language pass DST by values with the actual implementation being that a pointer is used. Returning them by value, however, seems trickier :)